# How to mount a file to a docker/compose container?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I want to deploy a few containers to a GCE VM created using GCP Container-Optimized OS image using my existing compose yaml file on GCP. One of the container needs a file from the host. With Container-Optimized OS instance, based on the tutorial from https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/docker-compose-on-container-optimized-os, I cannot run `docker-compose` but have to use a `docker/compse` container instead. One of my container is cloud-sql-proxy which needs a key json file. So far, I have not found a solution to pass this file from host to the container.

My question is:
Is it possible to pass a volume from the host to a container defined in Dockercompose file? I don't know how to add my file to one of the -v arg in blow command:

```
docker run --rm \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    -v "$PWD:/rootfs/$PWD" \
    -w="/rootfs/$PWD" \
    docker/compose:1.13.0 up
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After played around I guessed that if I use docker/compose image instead of `docker-compse` binary, the most important piece is to set up a volume for compose file itself:

```
 docker run -it --rm -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock   -v /home/Documents/labs:$(pwd) -w "$(pwd)" docker/compose:1.23.2 -f ./docker-compose run service sh
```

Inside a compose file, volumes are mounted from host to containers. There is no virtual docker host: there is only one docker host which is my own. `docker/compose` is just like any service in a compose file.